# R how to choose and do calculation for a pair of years in each group? (rolling time)

Tags: r

I have a dataset from 1963 to 2019, and 6,000+ companies. I want to group data by company, then calculate beta for every two years.
For example:

1. group by company, then choose 1963 and 1964, calculate,
2. for the same company, choose 1964 and 1965, calculate,

repeat above actions.

So each firm has 55 betas.

I tried to use a for loop: (RET and MKT are two columns)

```
result<-
  for (i in 1963:2017){
    filter(df,df$Year%in%c(i,i+1))%>%
      group_by(NAME)%>%
      summarise(beta=cov(RET,MKT)/var(MKT))
}
```

But get an empty result. Could some help me with this? Thank you.

My dput result is:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 
1963, 1963, 1963), COMNAM = c("A C F INDUSTRIES INC", "A J INDUSTRIES INC", 
"AMERICAN BRAKE SHOE CO", "NATIONAL ACME CO", "AIR REDUCTION INC", 
"ALLEGHENY POWER SYSTEMS INC", "ALLIED CHEMICAL CORP", "ALLIS CHALMERS MFG CO", 
"AMERICAN METAL CLIMAX INC", "AMERICAN BOSCH ARMA CORP"), MKT = c(0.051848, 
0.051848, 0.051848, 0.051848, 0.051848, 0.051848, 0.051848, 0.051848, 
0.051848, 0.051848), RET = c(0.047002, 0.034483, 0.056122, 0.057471, 
0.041475, 0.053846, 0.025424, 0.162393, 0.125, 0.157407)), row.names = c(915L, 
1936L, 4261L, 7852L, 12919L, 17179L, 18946L, 20649L, 21986L, 
25326L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please include minimal & representative sample data (e.g. use `dput(df[1:10, ])` and then include the output in your post). This may be a use case for `zoo::rollapply`.

Comment: Sure. I add the dput result for first 10 rows.

Comment: No, this is a monthly dataset, so for each company, there are 12 rows for each year. I think use year maybe easier, so I use year(Date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
library(dplyr)

result <- purrr::map_df(min(df$Year):(max(df$Year) - 1), function(i) {
             df %>%
              filter(Year%in% c(i,i+1)) %>%
              group_by(COMNAM)%>%
              summarise(year = paste(i, i + 1, sep = '-'),
                        beta = cov(RET,MKT)/var(MKT))
             })
```

This should give one combined dataset in `result` with a `year` column which will tell you `beta` is for which two years.

Comment: Thank you very much! this works perfectly. Does the purr::map_df works in this format:  purr::map_df(range for i, function(i){calculation})? and could you explain more on the difference between using a for-loop and purr::map_df? Thanks

Comment: `map_*` variants are same as for loop but since you are using `dplyr`, I thought of using a function in `tidyverse` eco-system. `min(df$Year):(max(df$Year) - 1)` creates a range of years and for each of that year we apply the calculation in the function.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you for your help!!